# xUnit : Setup tests with statements

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I am developing a web app, and in a web app also tests are very important. My web app is built in .net Core, so I test using xUnit.NET

I started to test the register action of my account controller. The test is:

```cs
public class AccountControllerTests
{
    private List<AppUser> users = new List<AppUser>();

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestSuccessFulRegistration()
    {
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager = Mocks.GetUserManager(users);
        SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager = Mocks.GetSignInManager(users);

        AccountController controller = new AccountController(userManager, signInManager, null);

        RegisterUser user = new RegisterUser
        {
            UserName = "testemail@testdomein.tld",
            Email = "testemail@testdomein.tld",
            Password = "Test123@"
        };


        ActionResult<ApiResult> actionResult = await controller.Register(user);

        ApiResult apiResult = actionResult.Value;

        Assert.True(apiResult.Succeeded, "ApiResult should be Succeeded if username and email are unique.");
        Assert.Empty(apiResult.Errors);
        Assert.Empty(apiResult.Message);
        Assert.Null(apiResult.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestRegistrationWithIncorrectPassword()
    {
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager = Mocks.GetUserManager(users);
        SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager = Mocks.GetSignInManager(users);

        AccountController controller = new AccountController(userManager, signInManager, null);

        RegisterUser user = new RegisterUser
        {
            UserName = "testemail@testdomein.tld",
            Email = "testemail@testdomein.tld",
            Password = "Test"
        };

        ActionResult<ApiResult> actionResult = await controller.Register(user);

        ApiResult apiResult = actionResult.Value;

        Assert.False(apiResult.Succeeded, "Registration should fail if password does not have numbers and special symbols.");
        Assert.NotEmpty(apiResult.Errors);
        Assert.Empty(apiResult.Message);
        Assert.Null(apiResult.Object);
    }
}
```

I created a static `Mocks` class, which mocks the `UserManager<Appuser>` and the `SignInManager<AppUser>` Now I tried to test registering. I have in the startup class of my app set that a password should have digits and nonalphanumeric characters. However, if I use `test` as password, the userManager.createAsync returns true. The user manager is mocked like this:

```cs
public static UserManager<TUser> GetUserManager<TUser>(List<TUser> ls) where TUser : class
{
    var store = new Mock<IUserStore<TUser>>();

    var userManager = new Mock<UserManager<TUser>>(store.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    userManager.Object.UserValidators.Add(new UserValidator<TUser>());
    userManager.Object.PasswordValidators.Add(new PasswordValidator<TUser>());

    userManager.Setup(x => x.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

    userManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success).Callback<TUser, string>((x, y) => ls.Add(x));
    userManager.Setup(x => x.UpdateAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

    return userManager.Object;
}
```

CreateAsync does always return success, but I don't even know how to write that the `IOptions<Identity>` are used.

Comment: Is it bad to use fake objects, instead of mocking? Because thats a bit easier. But maybe not the best practice?

Comment: What do you mean by "fake objects"?

Comment: As a rule, what you're testing should ideally be your actual code, and if that's not possible then something as close to it as possible. You say "CreateAsync does always return success" - and it does that because you've told it to: `userManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success)` - it doesn't validate the password because it's just a dumb mock and it doesn't know it should. What I would suggest are a) have tests that your validator works and b) have a test to make sure it's called during registration.

Comment: @stuartd With "fake objects", I mean that I create a "FakeUserManager<TUser>" for example. Or a "FakeSignInManager<TUser>"

Comment: Also, I know that returning true is done by that rule of code, but actually my question is how to add a statement, which should return the actual real data. I want to mock my objects, because I read that testing to databases is not the right way. Is it really best practice to test the validator *and* test of it is called?

Comment: The question is - what **exactly** are you trying to test?

Comment: @stuartd Exactly I want to test, if I register, if the correct responses are send back. So if I use a email and correct password, should be returned true, but if I use an email adres which is already in use, it should return false, even as when I try to register with a password without nonalphanumerical letters.

Comment: And that's your problem. You are writing a _Unit_ Test with an _End-To-End_ Test in mind. As stauartd said: Separate them. 1. Test your validator. 2. Test your registration => one time with the Validator-Mock returning success, then the registration should set the properties accordingly to success and one time with the Mock setup to fail, in which case the registration should set the properties according to fail. So if you integrate both, you'll know validation will validate correctly, and registration will handle validation results correctly.

Comment: ^^ What I tried to say: when testing the registration, you don't care if the actual credentials are valid or not. You want to test if the possible _validation results_ are handled correctly.